# Wireless card disappeared in Ubuntu 14.04 (Ralink RT2860)

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, hardware, ralink

I have an old Advent Milano netbook that has been running a light version of Win 7. 
I decided it was time to give Ubuntu a try and installed it on a partition, and it worked perfectly. It is now a couple of weeks later and the wireless card appears to have disappeared.
I tried booting back in to Win7 to use the device manager, but the card is no longer visible there either.

Grateful for all assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your wireless card no longer appears in Windows either, I don't think this is an Ubuntu driver problem.  **I think this is a hardware problem.**

1. *If your wireless card is integrated on your motherboard*, purchase a separate wireless card or USB dongle.
   **OR**
2. *If your wireless card is separate*, open the case and make sure that the card hasn't come loose out the socket. Alternatively, you can change which socket it is plugged in to.  Ultimately, I think your wireless card has seen its end-of-life and needs replacement.